# Retrofit accessing multiple models in Json response

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have some JSON below. Before I only had the `items` element in the JSON response and was using retrofit to access this with the following code. Which worked fine.

But now I have added the recommendation section, I have created the recommendation model but how do I now access the data from the recommendation/items section of the response?

**edit**
Maybe there is a better way to have this data returned. There could be maybe 500 items but only 20/30 lists so I thought it was better to split up instead of duplicating the data.

**JSON**

```
[
{
    "recommendation": [
        {
            "following": true,
            "list_id": "29",
            "list_name": "list29",
        },
        {
            "following": false,
            "list_id": "28",
            "list_name": "list28",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "items": [
        {
            "description": [
                "line1",
                "line2",
                "line3"
            ],
            "image1": "4367218/img1.jpg",
            "item_id": 5600,
            "title": "Title 1",
            "recommendation_id": 29
        },
        {
            "description": [
                "line1",
                "line2",
                "line3"
            ],
            "image1": "342345/img1.jpg",
            "item_id": 3600,
            "title": "Tite2",
            "recommendation_id": 28
        }
    ]
}
]
```

**Recommendation Model**

```
public class Recommendation {

    private Boolean following;
    private int listId;
    private String listName;

    public Boolean getFollowing() {
        return following;
    }

    // more getters and setters
}
```

**Item Model**

```
public class Item {

    private int item_id;
    private String title;
    private ArrayList<String> description;
    private String image1;
    private int recommendation_id;

    // more getters and setters
}
```

**Retrofit GET**

```
// feed
@GET("/items/{user_id}/{num_items}")
public void getFeedData(@Path("user_id") int user_id, @Path("num_items") Integer num_items, Callback<List<Item>> response);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
    "recommendation": [
        "data":{
            "following": true,
            "list_id": "29",
            "list_name": "list29"
        },
       "data": {
            "following": false,
            "list_id": "28",
            "list_name": "list28"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "items": [
        "data_item":{
            "description": [
                "line1",
                "line2",
                "line3"
            ],
            "image1": "4367218/img1.jpg",
            "item_id": 5600,
            "title": "Title 1",
            "recommendation_id": 29
        },
         "data_item":{
            "description": [
                "line1",
                "line2",
                "line3"
            ],
            "image1": "342345/img1.jpg",
            "item_id": 3600,
            "title": "Tite2",
            "recommendation_id": 28
        }
    ]
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model{

ArrayList<Data> recommendation ; 
ArrayList<DataItem> items ;
}
```

Data Model :

```
public class Data{

   private boolean following ;
   private String list_id ;
   private String list_name ;

}
```

DataItem Model :

```
public class DataItem{

private String description [];
private String image1 ;
private String item_id ;
private String title ;
private String recommendation_id ;

}
```

Comment: Can I ask how I should be using this Model in the adapter. I currently am doing Model model = getItem(position);
        DataItem item = model.getDataItem().get(position); but its only taking the first dataItem in the array and then makes another request

Comment: You can pass the arraylist of dataItem in adapter in constructor then in getCount you should do dataItem.size() and then it will iterate to all position of dataItem

Comment: If i set ArrayAdapter<DataItem> it works fine, its just when its ArrayAdapter<Model>

Comment: Model is an Object not a list so issue will arise in that case you have to use DataItem only

Comment: if you need then in same adapter then why are you using two JsonArray. club data and dataItem in one array and use it. It will make you life more easy

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting your JSON root from array to object:

```
{
    "recommendation": [...],
    "items": [...]
}
```

Then have Retrofit parsed JSON response into a new model, let's say `Response`:

```
public class Response {
    private Recommendation[] recommendation;
    private Item[] items;
    // your getters
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm trying it now. Should it not be an ArrayList in the response model?

Comment: If your response return a list of things, each item represented by `Response` class, then have Retrofit parsed it into `Response[]`, and your JSON should have array as root, each array item should follow schema in my answer

Comment: If you mean how to retrieve `items` then have a getter in `Response` says `getItems() { return items; }` and call that method in your adapter